# Is it possible to detect if an image has been resized without maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: image-processing

Say we have some images (from photographs) in some aspect ratio, like 16:9, that may have been resized and downsampled from another aspect ratio, like 4:3. Then the image would be squished along its height dimension. Or resized from one arbitrary shape to another, where the ratio of the long to short edge has been squished. Maybe another way to say this is that one spatial dimension has been downsampled to a greater extent than another.

I'm curious if there's a basic way to take an educated guess about whether an axis of an image has been squished. My intuition about this is that it might be possible by checking the Fourier transform of the image, because the frequencies along the image axis that was "squished" would be shifted higher than before the transform.

Is this a reasonable intuition, and what would the implementation look like?

Comment: Surely it depends on the manner of resampling? Most cameras apply a low-pass filter to the sensor output, and any reasonable resizing algorithm will do the same. So I'm not sure you'd see a determinable difference in horizontal versus vertical frequency response.